# MYSQL join query not to show specific condition not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query , where I am trying to have this in a search for first_name or last_name or email , but don't include any where role_id <> 0 : Here is the Query:

```
select *, `users`.`id` as `user_id` 
from `users` 
inner join `roles` on `users`.`role_id` = `roles`.`id` 
where `users`.`first_name` LIKE %test% 
   or `users`.`last_name` LIKE %test% 
   or `users`.`email` LIKE %test% 
   and `users`.`role_id` <> 0 
order by `first_name` asc limit 2 offset 0
```

This is not working its showing users with role_id = 0 ? could you explain why? and how to fix it

Thanks

Comment: Fill in your parameters please.

Comment: wrap all the or conditions within `()` followed by AND

Comment: First off, I don't think you can combine `*` with other parameters in SELECT.  Perhaps `users.*` but not just `*`.

Comment: I filled it out , now you can see it better

Comment: its working with * thats not my question

Comment: @user3150060 Can you prepare sqlfiddle, so we could reproduce your error?

Comment: I needed the Bracets that was the problem

Comment: @user3150060 Obviously your role table has a 0 ID in it.  (and you're missing parenthesis around the ands for the or)  I still can't get past the horrific `select *,` though...

Comment: its working ebyrob , you should try it your self :)

Comment: @user3150060 ebyrob has a good point about the select * this is almost never a good practice, you should identify your columns in the select statement.

Comment: I see your point I can change it its not really a big deal :)

Comment: how about users.* , roles.name , `users`.`id` as `user_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *, `users`.`id` as `user_id` 
from `users` 
inner join `roles` on `users`.`role_id` = `roles`.`id` 
where (`users`.`first_name` LIKE %test% 
   or `users`.`last_name` LIKE %test% 
   or `users`.`email` LIKE %test% )
   and `users`.`role_id` <> 0 
order by `first_name` asc limit 2 offset 0
```

Brackets help differentiate what logic goes with what.  Without the brackets you are saying:

first name matches, or second name matches or (email matches and roleid matches)